# Need some modelling advice for my University Final Major Project

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: Humanoid Robot Sketch]

[image: Stable Diffusion Experiment]

I'm new to blender, I'm working on a 3D animation for my Final Major project at University. I've provided a sketch of one of the characters which will be a humanoid robot, also I attached an AI-generated render I made from my sketch using Stable Diffusion. I'll be doing more detailed full-body sketches for the character, but for now, I want to experiment with modelling just the head for learning and I can use it for part of the research and experimentation for my project report. I picture his head being hollow and then you'll be able to see through the spaces between the abstract shapes, I also imagine when looking at the side of the head you'll see a circular hole with a turning gyroscope inside, like a brain.

I've got a bunch of 3D design experience, mostly C4D/Redshift, some Maya, quite comfortable with hard surface modelling techniques. Although I've not attempted modelling a character like this before, I'm mostly wondering about how I'm going to create all the fragmented shapes and form a human-shaped head from them. At the moment I'm going through the donut tutorial for Blender, but soon I would like to start attempting to model this. I would really appreciate some advice on some good 3D modelling approaches to create a character like this.

Thank you for your time.

Nat

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. You should show efforts towards reaching your goal, describing what you have tried and why it failed, so we don't risk recommending something you already know. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site. If you could [edit] your post to focus on where you are stuck we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: alternatively you can ask about it at [Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Select all the edge loops where you want a separation and press <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to rip:

[image]

Then select all and in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel select *Individual Origins*:

[image]

Scale down, it will scale all the different parts individually:

[image]

Give your object a *Solidify* modifier to give it thickness:

[image]

You can also give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, in that case it will need additional edge loops to keep the edges sharp:

[image]